# C++ MFC AutoComplete ComboBox

Tags: c++, combobox, autocomplete, mfc

Is there anyway to have the autocomplete for MFC ComboBox?
When user enter characters the list of matching strings appears in dropdown combox. Something like this. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

[image]

This combobox is `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`. Maybe it's not exactly autocomplete, but searching

Comment: Is this a combobox in a dialog box, or is it a `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`? Possible solutions for one may not work for the other.

Comment: You can add autocomplete to any edit control, in case that is the ultimate goal. [Providing a custom autocomplete source for an edit control](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130923-00/?p=3163) illustrates the fundamentals. [IAutoComplete2::SetOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nf-shldisp-iautocomplete2-setoptions) offers a wide range of customization options.

Comment: I think you described filtering, not autocomplete. What behavior do you want?

Comment: this combobox is CMFCPropertyGridProperty. Maybe it's not autocomplete, but searching.

Comment: I have asked about this before. I think you have to roll your own customization.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following link. It could give you a solution.

> The basic idea is that every time the text in the edit box changes,
> check to see if there is any text in the drop down list that is
> prefixed by this edit box text. Handle the `CBN_EDITUPDATE` message to
> get the text change notifications, and use `GetWindowText()` to get the
> text. `CComboBox::SelectString` will look for a string in the list which
> is prefixed by the given string, and select it into the edit box.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783/Implementing-an-autocompleting-Combobox

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That linked article does not do what was asked. It is quite clear that the poster wants the drop-down list of data to filter down to include only those that start with the text that they have typed.